# Update a chartjs by javascript function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an issue with chartjs I want to update values from server side but first I want to call a function that would do this, but it won't execute. Below  is mine code:

```
window.onload = function() {
//tested values
                     var lab = {
                      global property
                         fontSize: 8,
                         boxWidth: 20
                     }
                     var data = {
                         labels: ["Done", "In progress", "Not"],
                         datasets: [{label: '# of Votes',
                             data: [4, 15, 3],
                             backgroundColor: [
                                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                 '#ccf9d6'
                             ],
                             borderColor: [
                                 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                 'green'
                             ],
                             borderWidth: 1
                         }]
                     }
                     addData('#myChart',lab, data);
                 };

//function
                 function addData(chart, label, data) {
                     chart.data.labels.push(label);
                     chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {dataset.data.push(data);});
                 chart.update();
                 }
```

and error : `Cannot read property 'labels' of undefined`

HTML code:

```
<canvas id="myChart"   class="chartjs hidden-xs" width="300" height="150"  ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you are passing a string ID for the chart in and then trying to access properties of it - resulting in your error. You are doing `"myChart".data.labels.push(label);` which is why you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'labels' of undefined` because `"#myChart.data"` is `undefined`.

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) I was able to give it a try for you.

```
function addData(chartID, label, data) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById(chartID).getContext('2d');
  var newChartData = {};
  newChartData.type = "bar";
  newChartData.data = {};
  newChartData.data.labels = ["a","b","c"];
  newChartData.data.datasets = [];
  newChartData.data.labels.push(label);
  data.datasets.forEach((dataset) =>{newChartData.data.datasets.push(dataset);});
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, newChartData);
  myChart.update();
}
```

I was able to test it for you. Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6avtjuLg/

Comment: Try adding a type to newChartData. I will update my answer with the info

Comment: I added a fiddle for you as well.

Comment: why _lab_ need to be string if there I have properties like `fontSize` and `boxWidth` ?

Comment: those properties need to be in the config for scaleLabel. Here are the docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=scalelabel

Answer (score 0):

I see different errors here...

- when you call you `addData()` function, you pass a string value and not the Chart object.
- in your `lab` object didn't comment the phrase `"global property"`

see [my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/zkha4baa/)